# Splitting a String across 2 textviews

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, text, nsstring, textview

I am using 3 textviews to create simple columns in my iOS app. I am trying to split my string (varying lengths depending on article) across the 3.

The idea would be so that when one textview is filled, it then starts to fill the next etc.

I have already tried character counts, this does not account for line breaks and therefore doesn't work as I want it to be fixed without scrolling.

Comment: In Xcode or in your OS X/iOS app?

Comment: Xcode iOS Sdk, I am writing a iOS app

Comment: Take a look at [this one](http://foobarpig.com/iphone/coretext-example-column-layout-with-correctly-inverted-text.html)